# Equalation of rose (polar) 3d

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to plot a filled rose which its center is (30,30,30) and the radius of it is 2. I wrote the following code:

> ```
> t = linspace(0,2*pi,201);
> r = sqrt(abs(2*sin(5*t)));
> [x y]=pol2cart(t,r);
> z=x;
> plot3(x+30,y+30,z)
> grid on;
> ```

and I got the following plot:
[image]

How can I plot a rose which its leaves are not only in XY plane?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get a rose with leaves that bend up, you can play around with the z-coordinate. For instance, you can try something like this:

```
z = 0.5 * (x.^2 + y.^2);
```

This results in

[image]

And since roses are red...

```
t = linspace(0,2*pi,201);
r = sqrt(abs(2*sin(5*t)));
[x y]=pol2cart(t,r);
z= 0.5*(x.^2+y.^2);
fill3(-x+30,-y+30,z, 'r')
alpha(0.5)
grid on;
```

[image]